# Target JSON response

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a JSON response that looks like this:

> {\"venues\":[{\"id\":1,\"photo\":\"https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com" }, ....

It has a key "venues" and then an array of objects. In Retrofit response:

```
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Venue>> call, Response<List<Venue>> response) {
            venues = response.body();
            venueAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

It fails with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Problem is I do not know how to tell Retrofit to target the collection that the "venues" key points to. How can I do this? I don't want to have to create another class Venues just because of this JSON response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this in your code .

**ResponseVenue Class**

```
public class ResponseVenue {

private List<VenuesBean> venues;

public List<VenuesBean> getVenues() {
    return venues;
}

public void setVenues(List<VenuesBean> venues) {
    this.venues = venues;
}

public static class VenuesBean {
    /**
     * id : 1
     * photo : https: //s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
     */

    private int id;
    private String photo;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }
}
}
```

Then use in your code .

```
public void onResponse(Call<ResponseVenue> call, Response<ResponseVenue> response) {
    venues = response.body();
    venueAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Post **Venue** pojo class.
I think you pojo do not match with response json.

Answer (score 0):

Your retrofit response is set for this json output :

> [{\"id\":1,\"photo\":\"https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com" }, ....]

It directly map object into List. If you have only single array then you can change your json response like this, but if you have another key-value pair in this json response then you should try @KeLiuyue answer. Create an VenueResponse pojo class and it contain an List field to hold your Venue Pojo class.
After this retrieve your Venue Pojo like this:

```
public void onResponse(Call<ResponseVenue> call, Response<ResponseVenue> response) {
    venues = response.body().getVenues();
    venueAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
onResponse(Call<List<Venue>> call, Response<List<Venue>> response)
```

to

```
onResponse(Call<Venue> call, Response<Venue> response)
```

And Also in Api Interface of retrofit remove List and make only Venue